# Get "last updated" time for each file on master

Tags: github, github-api

I am fetching the master repo contents like this:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/Noitidart/Trigger-Community/git/trees/master
```

This uses the `trees` endpoint. This gives me all the files on master and its `file sha`. There is no `last updated` field.

I also have the following information, which is a list of all the commits on the repo:

```
GET http://api.github.com/repos/Noitidart/Trigger-Community/commits?per_page=100000000
```

However this contains `commit sha`, and I can't relate a `file sha` to a `commit sha` :(

As I am already doing two queries above, is there any way to use the info obtained between the two to get the "last updated" time of each file on master? I was hoping to avoid querying each `commit sha` for details, as that will be many many more queries and probably a burden on Github servers.